Prove the derivative of an element-wise function is the element-wise derivative of the function
My question comes from the activation function in a Neural Network, specifically in the backpropagation step.
I want to formally proof that, if a function A applies function B to each element of a matrix, then the derivative of function A is the derivative of function B applied to each element of the matrix.
I'm trying to do it by defining such an element wise function and then using the generalized derivative:
First let's define a function $\phi$ as a map where $A$ is an $n\times m$ matrix of real elements:
$$\phi: A\mapsto\Bbb{R}^{n\times m} $$
$$f: \Bbb{R}\mapsto \Bbb{R}$$
where
$$\phi({A}) = {B}$$
$${B} = (b_{ij}) = (f(a_{ij}))$$
So $\phi$ applies the function $f$ to each element of ${A}$.
Now, by the definition of derivative:
$$\lim_{\vert\vert{h}\vert\vert\to 0}\frac{\vert\vert f(x+h)-f(x)-Df(x)h \vert\vert}{\vert\vert h\vert\vert}=0$$
Using it for the map $\phi$, where both $A$ and $H$ are matrices of the same dimension:
$$\lim_{\vert\vert{H}\vert\vert\to 0}\frac{\vert\vert \phi(A+H)-\phi(A)-D\phi(A)H \vert\vert}{\vert\vert H\vert\vert}=0$$
Not sure if this step is correct:
$$\lim_{\vert\vert{h_{ij}}\vert\vert\to 0}\frac{\vert\vert f((a + h)_{ij})-f(a_{ij})-d_{ij}h_{ij} \vert\vert}{\vert\vert h_{ij}\vert\vert}=0$$
From here it follows that:
$$d_{ij} = \lim_{{h_{ij}}\to 0}\frac{f((a + h)_{ij})-f(a_{ij}) }{{h_{ij}}}$$
$$d_{ij} = f'(a_{ij})$$
Which would mean each element of the derivative of $\phi$ is just the derivative of $f$ evaluated at each element.
I'm not entirely certain of the steps I took, i would appreciate any feedback!

You need to be a little careful what you mean as the derivative of $\phi$. The (Frechet) derivative is given by $[D\phi(A)H]{ij} = f'([A]{ij})[H]_{ij} $.

Assuming all functions are applied elementwise, you can write a Taylor series in terms of Hadamard products/powers:
$$f(A+H) = f(A) + f'(A)\odot H + \tfrac12f''(A)\odot H^{\odot 2} + \ldots$$

You need to be careful with what you proved.
In the step where you say 'Not sure if this step is correct', you implicitly make an Ansatz for the derivative; namely, that $(D(A)H)_{ij} = d_{ij}h_{ij}$.
Assuming this Ansatz, you then show that necessarily $d_{ij} = f'(a_{ij})$.
This does not prove that $D(A)$ defined this way is indeed the derivative we are looking for.
What you must instead show is that given the Ansatz $(D(A)H)_{ij} = d_{ij}h_{ij}$ together with the proposed entries $d_{ij} = f'(a_{ij})$ for $D(A)$, then $D(A)$ defined this way is indeed the derivative.
To show this, you go one of your steps in reverse: by the Ansatz for $d_{ij}$, you know that
$$
\lim_{h_{ij} \rightarrow 0} \frac{|f((a+h)_{ij}) - f(a_{ij}) - d_{ij}h_{ij}|}{|h_{ij}|} = 0.
$$
Then, using that
$$
\|\phi(A+H) - \phi(A) - D(A)H\|^2 = \sum_{i,j} |f((a+h)_{ij}) - f(a_{ij}) - d_{ij}h_{ij}|^2
$$
and that $|h_{ij}| \leq \|H\|$, you find
$$\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
\frac{\|\phi(A+H) - \phi(A) - D(A)H\|^2}{\|H\|^2}
&= \frac{\sum_{i,j} |f((a+h)_{ij}) - f(a_{ij}) - d_{ij}h_{ij}|^2}{\|H\|^2}
\\
&\leq \sum_{i,j} \frac{|f((a+h)_{ij}) - f(a_{ij}) - d_{ij}h_{ij}|^2}{h_{ij}^2},
\end{split}\end{equation*}$$
from which you can deduce
$$
\lim_{H \rightarrow 0} \frac{\|\phi(A+H) - \phi(A) - D(A)H\|}{\|H\|} = 0.
$$
